# Setting up parameter by reference is throwing UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles, android-attributes

I want to set parameters by reference. In my case, it is color that will switch by custom app `Theme`. Problem is that at one place in my code it is throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` but in other places it is working fine. I'm using it in 50 different places but just here in this layout, it is not working. Probably problem is that it is layout which is inflated by `LayoutInflater`.

Here is my color name in `attr.xml` ->

```
<attr name="bgColor" format="reference"/>
```

Here is usage in `styles.xml` inside my custom `Theme`:

```
<style name="AppThemeBlueDark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
   ...
   <item name="bgColor">@color/darkred</item>
   ...
</style>
```

Here is usage of this referenced color in XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="52dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="?attr/bgColor">
    ...
    Other Views
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030051 a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:946)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5012)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:660)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:244)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:240)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:236)
```

Comment: Test case try this `<attr name="bgColor" format="reference|color" />`

Answer (score 0):

Change below line

```
<attr name="bgColor" format="reference"/>
```

to

```
<attr name="bgColor" format="color"/>
```

And use 
`android:backgroundTint="?attr/bgColor"`
insted of `android:background="?attr/bgColor"`

Comment: weird thing is that it is working on other places in my app without any issues. Only this single layout is causing issues

Comment: same problem. And I'm using it in different situation in this xml. For example `TextView` color. Everywhere it is throwing same exception

Comment: Can you check with the theme of your class in which u r using this layout?
as it seems you have applied different theme to your activity which doesn't have that attribute defined

Comment: This was a problem. I used my `Application` class to initialize `LayoutInflater` which caused this problem. If I use `Activity` it is working. `LayoutInflater.from(this)` instead of `LayoutInflater.from(app)`